# Linear stability of a given system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Let $A\left(t\right)$ be continuous on $\left[t_{0},\infty\right)$ and $\displaystyle{\lim \inf_{t \to \infty} \int_{t_{0}}^{t} A\left(s\right)ds>-\infty}$. Show that if the state transition matrix is $\Phi\left(t,t_{0}\right):=\Phi\left(t\right)\Phi^{-1}\left(t_{0}\right)$, where $\Phi\left(t\right)$ is a fundamental matrix for 
\begin{equation}
    x^{\prime}=A\left(t\right)x
    \label{nonautonomous}
\end{equation}
 then the zero solution of the system is uniformly stable.

Comment: Hmm, set $A=1$. Then $\dot{x} = x$ and the origin is certainly is certainly not stable in any sense.

Comment: @copper.hat Isn't A a matrix ?

Comment: What would the relevant matrix be for the system in my previous comment?????

Comment: Does Identity matrix satisfy the given limit condition?  I couldn't get even what does that condition mean.

Comment: Well, $\liminf_{t \to \infty} (t-t_0) > -\infty$, so the condition is satisfied. However, we have $x(t) = x(t_0) e^{t-t_0}$ so clearly the system is unstable.

Comment: Another ask & run...